# Error in polygonData/default(data) : Dont know how to get path data from object of class numeric

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sp

I have a function that creates a leaflet map from data outputs of other functions. One of my outputs is a spatialPolygonsDataFrame, which is the result of a buffer of groups of points using gBuffer, followed by gUnaryUnion to dissolve each group into a single polygon. Finally a data frame is added to it. This output is named clusterBuffer and is called in the following function (simplified for the purpose of the question).

```
compileLeaflet <- function(clusterBuffer){

 # Create condition to decide whether or not the object gets mapped
 iff <- function(cond,x,y) {
     if(cond) x else y
   }

 map <- leaflet()  


 map <- addProviderTiles(map, "CartoDB.Positron")


 # Plot cluster areas on map
 iff((is.null(clusterBuffer)),
    map,
    map <- addPolygons(map, data = clusterBuffer, color = "red")
    )


 map <<- map

}
```

My issue is this: the object will map if I run the code in the function line by line (not as a function). However, when I try to create the `map` object by calling the function, I get:

`Error in polygonData.default(data) :  Don't know how to get path data from object of class numeric`

Is the fact that it gives an error when it's inside the function due to the way I've written the code? Although it's a spatialPolygonsDataFrame, could the use of `gUnaryUnion` be causing formatting issues?

I render many other objects in this map using similar code all in the same function, but they're either rasters, or just derived from points -- I don't have much experience with polygons in leaflet.

Any advice on trouble shooting (format checks, syntax advice, techniques to isolate the issue, etc.) are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!